# Intellij shortuct to create a line between two lines?

Tags: intellij-idea, shortcut

Say I have two lines

```
line 39: foo
line 40: bar
```

My cursor is one line 39, and I want to write some stuff right below, moving the content of line 40 to line 41, like so:

```
line 39: foo
line 40: <cursor...>
line 41 bar
```

So: Given that I'm initially on line 39, how do I move my cursor down to line 40, shifting everything on line 40 and beyond to one line below?

The manual way is to drag my cursor all the way the end of line 30, hit enter. But if line 30 is a big line, it takes time to do this.

Comment: `End` key takes you to the end of the line. Or, better use `Down arrow` key to come to line 40 and press `Home` to come at the start of it, then press `Enter` to make a new line.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to achieve this (from obvious `End` then `Enter` combo to IdeaVim's `o`), but the Intellij's way to do it would be `Shift + Enter` hotkey.

The shortcut is called `Start New Line` in `Editor's Action` keymap and can be changed to your preference.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Shift+Enter .
Check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html#editor_lines_code_blocks